# Why are fields different when used in an arrow expression?

Tags: alloy

The following signature describes the state of a photo-management application:

```
sig ApplicationState {
    catalogs: set Catalog,
    catalogState: catalogs -> one CatalogState
}
```

A signature, of course, creates a set. In this case, it creates a set of ApplicationStates:

```
ApplicationState0
ApplicationState1
...
```

catalogs is a field. It maps each ApplicationState to a set of Catalog values:

```
ApplicationState0, Catalog0
ApplicationState0, Catalog1
ApplicationState1, Catalog0
...
```

catalogState is also a field. It maps each ApplicationState to a relation. The relation is:

```
catalogs -> one CatalogState
```

That relation says: Map each value of catalogs to one CatalogState value. We already saw catalogs, which I'll repeat here:

```
ApplicationState0, Catalog0
ApplicationState0, Catalog1
ApplicationState1, Catalog0
...
```

So, the relation says to map each of those tuples to one CatalogState, like so:

```
ApplicationState0, Catalog0, CatalogState0
ApplicationState0, Catalog1, CatalogState0
ApplicationState1, Catalog0, CatalogState0
...
```

Okay, back to catalogState. Earlier we said that it maps each ApplicationState to a relation, and we just saw what that relation is. So, I believe that catalogState denotes a relation with arity=4, like so:

```
ApplicationState0, ApplicationState0, Catalog0, CatalogState0
ApplicationState0, ApplicationState0, Catalog1, CatalogState0
ApplicationState0, ApplicationState1, Catalog0, CatalogState0
...
```

But, when I run the Alloy Evaluator, it says that catalogState is a ternary relation. My takeaway from this example is:

1. Usually a field name denotes a relation.
2. A field name used in an arrow expression does not denote a relation. Rather, it denotes column 2 of the relation (the range of the relation).

Is that right? Where is this explained in the Software Abstractions book?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Section 4.2.2 of *Sofware Abstractions* (p. 97 in the second edition) begins

> Relations are declared as fields of signatures.

That addresses at least part of your question, I think.  (I think it may be helpful to work through the index entries for 'field' and relation and read every section they point to.)

You say

> A field name used in an arrow expression does not denote a relation. Rather, it denotes column 2 of the relation (the range of the relation).

It may sound pedantic, but no: field names always denote relations.  Within the context of a signature declaration however, they are implicitly prefixed with `this.`, which removes the first column of the relation.  In your declaration `catalogState: catalogs -> one CatalogState`, the reference to `catalogs` is indeed a reference to a binary relation over ApplicationState and Catalog.  In this context, however, it's silently expanded to `this.catalogs`, which evaluates to a set of Catalog individuals.  The keyword `this` is introduced in section 4.2.2 of *Software Abstractions*.

The cardinality constraints on declarations may also be a complicating factor in your example; I won't try to explain their effect here.  I'll only say that when I have run into problems with cardinality constraints, I have often found that a very careful reading of the relevant parts of the language reference in Appendix B has generally sufficed to let me understand what was going on.  (I admit that sometimes it has taken more than one reading.)